# Patrón MVC, mejorar el controlador de una vista

Tags: java, java-swing, revisión-de-código

Soy relativamente nuevo en Java, estoy realizando una aplicación desktop con swing basándome en el patron MVC, y necesito consejos en como mejorar el controlador de una view.

La aplicación realizara el **CRUD** de la entidad **User**.

La **UserView** luce asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los botones: **Search... , Edit... , Add...**  abrirán diálogos que permitan realizar las operaciones en cuestión. (Ignorar el espacio libre ya que allí colocare otros componentes en el futuro).

Y los botones de Navegación: **First,Previous,Next,Last** permitirán de navegar a través los records de User presentes en la base de datos.

Ejemplo: al hacer click en next las labels de la view harán un setText con los datos del siguiente usuario presente en una lista y asi sucesivamente.

Esta es la clase **UserViewController**:

```
public class UserViewController {

    private UserView userView;

    private final UserService userService;
    private List<User> users;

    private int index = 0;

    public UserViewController(UserView userView) {
        this.userView = userView;
        this.userService = new UserService();
        users = userService.getAllUsers();
        addListeners();
        initUserView();
    }

    protected void initUserView() {
        initUserInUserView(getUserFromList(index));
    }

    public void addListeners() {
        userView.addButtonsListener(new CrudButtonsListener());
        userView.addNavigationListener(new NavigationButtonsListener());
        userView.addCancelListener(new DialogsCancelButtonsListener());
        userView.addAddUserOkListener(new DialgosSubmitButtonsListener(0));
        userView.addEditUserOkListener(new DialgosSubmitButtonsListener(1));
    }

    private class CrudButtonsListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            switch (e.getActionCommand()) {

            case "Clients":
                userView.getUserClients().show();
                break;

            case "Search...":
                userView.getSearchUser().show();
                break;

            case "Edit...":
                userView.getEditUser().setInputFieldData(getUserFromList(index));
                userView.getEditUser().show();
                break;

            case "Add...":
                userView.getAddUser().show();
                break;

            case "Delete":
                int userId = userView.getUserId();
                int option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(userView.getMainPanel(), "Do you want to delete this User?",
                        "Delete Warning", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

                deleteUser(userId, option);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private class NavigationButtonsListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            switch (e.getActionCommand()) {

            case "First":
                index = 0;
                initUserInUserView(getUserFromList(index));
                break;

            case "Previous":
                index--;
                if (index < 0) {
                    index = 0;
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(userView.getMainPanel(), "You have reached the beginning");
                    return;
                }
                initUserInUserView(getUserFromList(index));
                break;

            case "Next":
                index++;
                if (index >= users.size()) {
                    index = users.size() - 1;
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(userView.getMainPanel(), "The are not more records to show");
                    return;
                }
                initUserInUserView(getUserFromList(index));
                break;

            case "Last":
                index = users.size() - 1;
                initUserInUserView(getUserFromList(index));
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private class DialgosSubmitButtonsListener implements ActionListener {

        private final int actionListenerNum;

        public DialgosSubmitButtonsListener(int actionListenerNum) {
            this.actionListenerNum = actionListenerNum;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            switch (actionListenerNum) {
            case 0:
                if (userView.getAddUser().isEmptyFixedAttributes()) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(userView.getAddUser().getDialog(), "       Some Data is Empty");
                } else {
                    User user = userView.getAddUser().getNewUser();
                    user.setPassword("123");
                    createNewUser(user);
                }
                break;

            case 1:
                if (userView.getEditUser().isEmptyFixedAttributes()) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(userView.getEditUser().getDialog(),
                            "Fixed attributes can't be empty");
                } else {
                    User newUser = userView.getEditUser().getNewUser();
                    User oldUser = userView.getUser();
                    updateUser(oldUser, newUser);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private class DialogsCancelButtonsListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            userView.getAddUser().dispose();
            userView.getEditUser().dispose();
            userView.getSearchUser().dispose();
            userView.getUserClients().dispose();
        }
    }

    private void initUserInUserView(User user) {
        userView.setFieldData(user);
        userView.setUser(user);
    }

    private void createNewUser(User newUser) {
        userService.createUser(newUser);
        users.add(newUser);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(userView.getAddUser().getDialog(),
                "User *** " + newUser.getId() + " *** created with success");
        userView.getAddUser().clear();
    }

    private void updateUser(User oldUser, User newUser) {
        newUser.setPassword(oldUser.getPassword());
        userService.updateUser(newUser, oldUser.getId());
        updateUserFromList();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(userView.getEditUser().getDialog(),
                "User *** " + oldUser.getId() + " *** updated successfully");
    }

    private void deleteUser(int userId, int option) {
        if (option == 0) {
            userService.deleteUser(userId);
            deleteUserFromList(userId);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(userView.getMainPanel(), "User *** " + userId + " *** deleted with success");
        }
    }

    private User getUserFromList(int index) {
        return users.get(index);
    }

    private void updateUserFromList() {
        users.clear();
        users = userService.getAllUsers();
    }

    private void deleteUserFromList(int userId) {
        Iterator<User> iter = users.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            User user = iter.next();
            if (user.getId() == userId) {
                iter.remove();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

La clase **UserService** se encarga de realizar las operaciones CRUD y de obtener los datos necesarios de la base de datos.

- **CrudButtonsListener()** se encarga de abrir los diálogos.
- **NavigationButtonsListener()** permite visualizar y navegar a través de todos los records de user presentes iterando en la lista users que contiene dichos records.
  Me gustaría mejorar el numero de lineas de código, debería separar los últimos métodos de la clase y meterlos en otra clase llamada utils?
- **DialogsSubmmitButtonsListener()** los diálogos contienen botones para hacer submmit y realizar el crud.
- **DialogsCancelButtonsListener()** cada dialogo tiene un button cancel/quit, esta clase se encarga de cerrar los diálogos al hacer click en estos botones.

Debería separar los métodos que se encuentran al final de la clase y ponerlos en otra clase **"ControllersUtils"** ?

Consejos para mejorar este controlador.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En general el código lo veo bien; cada uno tiene su estilo y hay cosas que yo haría distinto, pero entraríamos en el campo de las opiniones y es mejor evitarlo.

Detalles que creo que objetivamente mejorarían el código:

- Tienes varias clases anidadas con funciones específicas. Al ser la clase principal no muy grande no veo un problema que sigan ahí, pero te estabas preguntando si mover los métodos creados debajo a otro sitio. Yo movería ese código hacía arriba, dejando las clases anidadas abajo del todo por un tema de orden: código de la clase principal y luego las anidadas (también se podría hacer al revés, el objetivo es agrupar el código). Esto es puramente por legibilidad.
- Como te comenté ayer en el chat de SOes, es mejor poner a cada botón un *action command* para no usar el texto del botón para identificarlo, ya que no te permitiría cambiar de idioma fácilmente tu UI.
- Tienes un método con lo siguiente:

  ```
  private void updateUserFromList() {
      users.clear();
      users = userService.getAllUsers();
  }
  ```

  La primera línea limpia la lista de objetos, pero esta llamada es innecesaria puesto que a conntinuación le asignas **otra** lista a ese atributo, con lo que la original se descarta (el recolector de basura)